# Weaker version of Goursats theroem

Tags: complex-analysis, greens-theorem, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have a homework problem that states:
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open. Suppose that $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $C^1$. Show that:

$\int_{T}f dz = 0$

Where $T$ is an arbitrary triangle contianed in $\Omega$.

My attempt so far:

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Write $f=u+iv$ and identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2, \ \tilde{f}:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} u(x,y) \\ v(x,y) \end{pmatrix}$. Denote $\Delta$ the surface bounded by $T$ in the plane. Using Greens theorem:

$\int_{T}f dz = \int_{T} \langle \tilde{f}, \text{dx}\rangle = \int_{\Delta}\partial_x v -\partial_y u \text{dvol} = 0$, using Cauchy-Riemann.

Does this work as a valid proof?

Comment: I'm not really sure why this should be a weaker version of Goursat. The theorem I have in mind is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem). It might be helpful if you give a specific version of the theorem you have in mind

Comment: Your equality $f\, dz = \langle \tilde{f}, \text{dx}\rangle$ doesn't seem quite right ($f\,dz = (u+iv)(dx + i\,dy)$).

Comment: Its weaker bc we assume f is continuously differentiable. For the normal Goursat we only assume f to be holomorphic

Comment: How would you transform f dz into a real Integral then?

Comment: It turns out that if a function is holomorphic then it is analytic and hence is C^k for all k, so this is not really a weakening. If you are taking your first course in complex analysis then perhaps you have not seen this yet since the proof I know uses Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: You don't transform $f dz$ into a real integral, you separate it into its real and imaginary parts using the formula given by @user8268. Then you use Green's theorem on the two pieces separately and find that one CR equation tells you the curl of the real part is 0 and the other CR equation tells you the curl of the imaginary part is 0.

Comment: I have done it like this now, 
I do not like the notation of the integrals with both dx and dy in them, is there any different way to write this?


$\int_{T}f dz = \int_T (u+iv)(\text{dx}+i\text{dy})) = \int_t(u\text{dx}-v\text{dy}) +int_T (v\text{dx}+u\text{dy}) = \int_T \langle \begin{pmatrix} u \\ -v \end{pmatrix}, \text{dr} \rangle +  \int_T \langle \begin{pmatrix} v \\ u \end{pmatrix}, \text{dr} \rangle = \iint_\Delta (-\partial_x v - \partial_y u)\text{dxdy} + \iint_\Delta (\partial_x u - \partial_y v)\text{dxdy} = 0$